# Notice : add_theme_support( 'post-formats' ) was called incorrectly

Tags: php

I updated WordPress to 5.6 version and now I got the message :

```
Notice: add_theme_support( 'post-formats' ) was called incorrectly. You need to pass an array of post formats. Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This message was added in version 5.6.0.) in /Users/pro/Documents/Sites/sitename/www/wp-includes/functions.php on line 5311
```

I noticed that this message disappeared when I deactivated the plugin Timber (TWIG).

In Timber I saw :

```
add_theme_support(
            'post-formats',
            array(
                'aside',
                'image',
                'video',
                'quote',
                'link',
                'gallery',
                'audio',
            )
        );
```

That seems correct. What's wrong?

Comment: Possibly but you need to contact Timber plugin support, 3rd party plugin dev support is off topic here

Comment: If you used `add_theme_support( 'post-formats' )` (missing second parameter) in your own theme, then it's normal for the notice - see the function [reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_theme_support/#changelog) which indicates the second parameter (one or more post formats) must be specified if you're on WordPress 5.6.0.

Comment: You can search your whole project code base for "add_theme_support" to see if there are other references to this function.

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_theme_support/ 
"add_theme_support( 'post-formats' ) 
will override the formats as defined by the parent theme, not add to it."